# Crop image to aspect ratio 1:1

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, image

I want to crop the image in React.js using for example the `<Crop url='example.com/image' width={96} height={96} aspectRatio={1}/>` component. 
[This solution](https://codepen.io/rikschennink/pen/rNNYWNb) looks pretty suitable but I can't set custom image size.

Comment: If you're setting the width and height anyway, isn't the `aspectRatio` information redundant then?

Comment: @Terry, I have a `1280x720` image and I have a wrapper for a `96x96` image, when I set the image size to `96x96`, it does not look proportional, so I need to convert `16:9` to `1:1` first and then I can set `96x96` for the image. Perhaps there is a better solution

Comment: That doesn't make sense. 96x96 is already 1:1.

Comment: Maybe you look for : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: @G-Cyrillus, ah, I forgot about `object-fit`.. The `object-fit: cover` works perfectly in my case. I can accept your comment as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) allow you to resize an image ,  crop it and preserve its ratio.

[`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) can set areas to be cropped.